# How to invoke Lambdas from Postman that are protected by an authorizer?

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization, postman, amazon-cognito, serverless

We have an Amazon API Gateway configured with Lambdas that are protected by an authorizer using Amazon Cognito. We also have a React app that uses the aws-amplify node module to authenticate and make callouts to our API. How do you make these same callouts to the API from Postman?

Comment: what kind of authorizer?

Comment: They use an aws_iam authorizer. @ThomasP1988

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this work. For anyone else that has the same issue, I wanted to post the solution. I was correctly using the AWS signature type for authorization, but I was not adding the correct headers to the request. Your request needs the following headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Answer (score 0):

In postman, click on authorization, then on type, here you have "AWS signature", you can fill your information to sign your request for aws_iam authorizer.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. I have an IAM user with the access and secret keys entered in Postman. Then I enter my region and 'execute-api' for the service name. However, it gives the error message 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.'